# Oracle- Determine if row is a result of a join returning more than 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, is their any way to determine if a row is only showing because of a join that has caused more than 1 row to return?

I'll explain:

I have 2 tables, say, SO and PO for this example.

SO is the driving table, and joins onto PO. PO can return more than 1 record per SO. This is desired, however I want to be able to have a column that indicates if the SO records of the result set are duplicated (as in are only showing because the PO join caused it to duplicate).

I want to use this identifier in Crystal Reports to suppress the first half of the fields on the report, as this is duplicated data that doesn't need to be shown more than once.

I should also add that I am performing some grouping on this data, which I just realized means that I can't do a huge amount unless I add them to the group by, which I cannot do.

Comment: Without specifics, I'd use a [CASE statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) based the result of an aggregate (IE: COUNT) to return 1 or zero.  Which'd mean a GROUP BY clause

Comment: Will `distinct` keyword be any use to you? +1 for the interesting question.

Comment: Well that actually looks like it worked. I've put a COUNT(DISTINCT PO.LINK) (PO.LINK in this example is the key of the join that returns multiple rows). So all up, CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT PO.LINK) > 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END. Is this the direction you were thinking?

Comment: you will not be able to distinguish what you need to show and what you don't with count(po.link) (btw, I guess count(distinct po.link) should always return 1 if this is an equijoin, shouldn't it?) - you will only be able to see how many rows have actually been produced

Comment: Its a left outer join, so it could return nil.

Comment: If you can't do much with the query, you're left with putting the logic into the Crystal Report -- which is doable, using a running total.

Comment: Yep I think it might come to that. I will use a formula field and do something like 'IF PREVIOUS(COLUMN1) = COLUMN1 AND PREVIOUS(COLUMN2) = COLUMN2 and so on

Answer (score 1):

`row_number() over(partition by SO.join_id order by PO.something) as r`

And suppress SO.* output for rows where `r > 1`.

<strike>update: you don't neccessarily need to partition by join condition. partition by whatever you want to suppress.</strike>

```
13:35:44 SYSTEM@dwal> ed
Wrote file S:\\tools\buffer.sql

  1  select decode(rn, 1, owner) owner, object_type, cnt
  2    from (
  3      select owner, object_type,  count(*) cnt,
  4            row_number() over(partition by owner order by owner, object_type desc) rn
  5        from dba_objects
  6       where owner in( 'SYSTEM', 'OUTLN')
  7       group by owner, object_type
  8*   )
13:36:09 SYSTEM@dwal> / </s>

OWNER    OBJECT_TYPE                CNT
-------- ------------------- ----------
OUTLN    TABLE                        3
         PROCEDURE                    1
         LOB                          1
         INDEX                        5
SYSTEM   VIEW                        14
         TYPE                         1
         TRIGGER                      2
         TABLE PARTITION             47
         TABLE                      159
         SYNONYM                      8
         SEQUENCE                    20
         QUEUE                        4
         PROCEDURE                    1
         PACKAGE BODY                 1
         PACKAGE                      1
         LOB                         23
         INDEX PARTITION             72

OWNER    OBJECT_TYPE                CNT
-------- ------------------- ----------
         INDEX                      239

18 rows selected.
```

You will need multiple analytics for multiple columns in this case, which is expensive

Comment: I don't think this will work, as the join condition on SO is not included in my Group By (just updated my question then).